Eigenvalues with Hamming weight symmetry
Let $H$ be an $n \times n$ matrix and let $H_{x, y}$ be the $(x, y)^{\mathsf{th}}$ entry of $H$. Let $|x|$ be the Hamming weight of $x$, when written in binary.
Also, let it be that:
\begin{equation}
H_{x, y} =1 ~~\mathsf{when} ~~|x|=|y|, \\
=0 ~~~ \mathsf{otherwise.}
\end{equation}
I am trying to find the eigenvalues of $H$.

Note that $H$ is a very sparse matrix, but computing its eigenvalues seems to be a difficult task.

$H+I$ is an adjacency matrix of a disjoint union of complete graphs of "known" cardinalities (if $n \not = 2^k$ the computation is going to be messy, see maybe here). As per this answer, when we take disjoint unions, we just combine all the eigenvalues.
